# How tree behavior work in this table

Tags: mysql, algorithm, cakephp

This is a Cakephp tree behavior example. We can store 'n' number of parent child relationship in this table and  I didn't understand how does it work and how the lft, rght field contain the values. I want to understand tree behavior deeply.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
        id INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        parent_id INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        lft INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        rght INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(1, 'My Categories', NULL, 1, 30);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(2, 'Fun', 1, 2, 15);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(3, 'Sport', 2, 3, 8);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(4, 'Surfing', 3, 4, 5);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(5, 'Extreme knitting', 3, 6, 7);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES(6, 'Friends', 2, 9, 14);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (7, 'Gerald', 6, 10, 11);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (8, 'Gwendolyn', 6, 12, 13);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (9, 'Work', 1, 16, 29);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (10, 'Reports', 9, 17, 22);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (11, 'Annual', 10, 18, 19);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (12, 'Status', 10, 20, 21);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (13, 'Trips', 9, 23, 28);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (14, 'National', 13, 24, 25);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id, lft, rght)
VALUES (15, 'International', 13, 26, 27);
```

Comment: What do you want to understand?

Comment: How its work lft, rght field in this table and what is the algorithm to use these?

Comment: as stated in the manual [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#namespace-Cake\ORM\Behavior), TreeBehavior uses MPTT logic described [**here**](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

Comment: Have you read http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ or [Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/0123877334)?

Comment: Thanks to share me these link I will read.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following image will help you to understanding the algorithm for TreeBehavior.

Cakephp uses  MPTT logic for the TreeBehavior .

[image]

**This is stored in the table as below:**

[image]

For further reading please go through the below link:

https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/